# Type text in arbitrary position on Form

Tags: c#, winforms

Does anybody have an example on how to type letters onto a form, like in a graphics program? When I click in a position on the form, I want to be able to start typing and have my text show up on the form.

Comment: Please give more info. What software what platform, etc that you are coding for. It's easier to help if you give details of the problems that you are having.

Comment: @closers: stop it! I'm sick of people trying to close perfectly valid questions. Not everybody is a native English speaker. Make some effort to figure out what the asker wants.

Comment: I agree with MusiGenesis, if you don't understand a question then ask for clarification. And give the asker a few days at least.

Comment: And if you have enough rep to close, you have enough rep to edit the question and rephrase it so it's clear what the asker intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this answer to an earlier question:

[Need help creating control to display data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342689/need-help-creating-control-to-display-data/1342891#1342891)

Down at the bottom of the answer are links to a sample application and its source code.  This sample shows how to do editing in-place of graphically-draw text.  The app basically moves a textbox over the graphics to allow text entry and editing, and then when the user clicks away from the textbox the box is made invisible and the entered text is drawn onto the control surface.  You can modify this technique to do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I cannot give the exact example that you're looking for.  However, I can recommend that you to look at open source projects and try to find an application that does something similar what you need.  Then you simply can look at the source code.

You can start with sites like [CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/) and [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/).

With a quick search on CodePlex I was able to find two application that might help you:

[Image to Text Art](http://imagetotextart.codeplex.com/)

[Text Image Generator](http://textimagegenerator.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

If you like to write something on your form you can use GDI+ features.To do so you can override the paint method of your form like this:

```
protected override OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{

}
```

[PaintEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.painteventargs.aspx) class has a reference to a graphics object that let you do some graphical stuff on your form.
For your task you can use DrawString to write on the surface of your form
BTW you should be informed that every time the form surface becomes invalidated it will be painted again and maybe you want to keep what you want to write on your form in a list so that you can write them every time the form is painted again.